# Pandas DataFrame chunks: writing a DataFrame generator object to_csv

Tags: pandas, generator, chunks

I'm reading a large amount of data from a database via pd.read_sql(...chunksize=10000) which generates a df generator object.

While I can still work with that dataframe in merging it with pd.merge(df,df2...) some functions are no longer available, such as df.to_cs(...)

What is the best way to handle that? How can I write such a dataframe to a CSV? Do I need to iterate over it manually?

Answer (score 3):

You can either process each chunk individually, or combine them using e.g. `pd.concat` to operate on all chunks as a whole.

Individually, you would indeed iterate over the chunks like so:

```
for chunk in pd.read_sql(...chunksize=10000):
    # process chunk
```

To combine, you can use `list comprehension`:

```
df = pd.concat([chunk for chunk in pd.read_sql(...chunksize=10000)])
#process df
```